# $.ajax post redirect via php not working

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am trying to  redirect via php on $.ajax post but it seems be not working

this is ajax

```
$("#customer_logout_link").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            var: 'value'
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

this is php code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["var"]))
{
    header("location: accounts_login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

ajax hit the php code and response also shown in success . but i want to redirect from php . what i am missing ?

Comment: on what url are you sending the ajax request? `$.ajax({ url: 'some.php'`...

Comment: any php error in the response ?

Comment: var is use for declare as variable like. var self = 'some string'; use something else at data: {var:'value'},

Comment: Use javascript to redirect? An ajax request is another different http request from the page so the redirect header applies only to that request.

Comment: You have many [unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231134/neeraj?tab=questions), right? Do you know how to do? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Thanks for all your answerers and future readers :)

Comment: oh , right , thanks for pointing me out  will close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this because the redirection will be done into the AJAX request. But you could detect something from PHP to redirect in PHP.

Example :

```
$("#customer_logout_link").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {var:'value'},
      dataType: 'text',
      success:function(data){
        if (data.indexOf('Location:') === 0) {
                window.location.href = data.substr(10);
            }
      }
    });
});
```

And in your PHP :

```
if (isset($_POST["var"]))
{

    echo "Location: accounts_login.php";
    exit;
}
```