# Facing issues with redirection of file from one php file to another

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am using HTML, Ajax, PHP

What I want to implement is, when the user login and `type="student"` must redirect to `simple.php` file else if `type="marker"` should be redirected to another `marker.php` file. if credentials are wrong then error message should be shown on the same login page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            var username1=$('#username').val();
            var password1=$('#password').val();
            var type1=$('#utype').val();

            $.post("lo.php",{x:username1,y:password1,z:type1},function(validEntry){
                $('#resultDiv').html(validEntry);
            })
            /*
            $.ajax({

                url:"lo.php",
                data:{username2:'username1',password2:'password1',type2:'type1'},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#resultDiv').text(data);
                }
            })*/
        })
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my PHP sample code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','multilevel');

//print $_POST['name']; 
$username3=$_POST['x'];
$password3=$_POST['y'];
$type3=$_POST['z'];

$query="select * from login where username='$username3' and  password='$password3' and type='$type3'";

$run=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$check_entry=mysqli_num_rows($run);




while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) { 
    if ($row['username'] == $username3 && $row['password'] == $password3 && $row['type'] == 'Student') 

    {
        $_SESSION["username1"] = $username3; 
        header("Location:simple.php");

    } elseif ($row['username'] == $username3 && $row['password'] == $password3 && $row['type'] == 'Marker') {


        $_SESSION["username1"] = $username; 
        header("Location:simple1.php");
    } else {

        print "<h2>Username or password is incorrect</h2>";
        exit();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: So what's the issue are you getting?

Comment: Maybe check [$.ajax post redirect via php not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148087/ajax-post-redirect-via-php-not-working)

Comment: here when the user is type=student, what ever data present in the simple.php is being displayed on the same login page but i want to redirect to simple.php

Comment: Are all the values coming through to your post page as expected?

Comment: no for now i am not getting anything

Answer (score 0):

You must not redirect using php header when using ajax, you need to listen to the server response then  redirect using jquery on the front end based on the response.

Your server side :

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$data     = array();
$redirect = array();
$message  = array();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'multilevel');

$username3 = $_POST['x'];
$password3 = $_POST['y'];
$type3     = $_POST['z'];

$query = "SELECT * from login where username='$username3' and  password='$password3' and type='$type3'";

$run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$check_entry = mysqli_num_rows($run);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) { 
    if ($row['username'] == $username3 && $row['password'] == $password3 && $row['type'] == 'Student') 
        {
        $_SESSION["username1"] = $username3; 
        $redirect['redirect']  = "simple.php"; //redirect
        $message['success']    = "ok";

    } elseif ($row['username'] == $username3 && $row['password'] == $password3 && $row['type'] == 'Marker') {

        $_SESSION["username1"] = $username; 
        $redirect['redirect']  = "marker.php"; //redirect
        $message['success']    = "ok";
    } else {

        $message['error'] = "Username or password is incorrect";
    }

}

$data['message']   = $message;
$data['redirects'] = $redirect;

ob_end_clean();

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Then on the client side.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var username1=$('#username').val();
            var password1=$('#password').val();
            var type1=$('#utype').val();            
            $.ajax({

                url:"lo.php",
                data:{username2:'username1',password2:'password1',type2:'type1'},
                dataType :"json",
                encode : true,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.message.success == "ok"){
                        //if response is ok then login success
                var redirectUrl = JSON.stringify(data.redirects);
                redirectUrl = redirectUrl.replace(/[{"":}]/g, '');
                var url = redirectUrl.replace('redirect','');
                setTimeout(' window.location.href = "'+ url + '"; ', 6000);
                    $('#resultDiv').html("Login success redirecting...");
                    }else{
                       $('#resultDiv').text(data.message.error); 
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> NB : Things you need to take care of ;
>
> 1. Don't store password as plain text in the database, use password_hash() and password_verify() to secure your passwords.
> 2. Use prepared statements, to prevent sql injections as it stands your code is not safe,

Refer to the Manuel for more of what I've said above

Comment: thanks for the help  masivuye Cokile i am trying your answer.

Comment: masivuye i am trying to run but nothing is happening can i know y?

Comment: because of this maybe `$username3 = $_POST['x'];
$password3 = $_POST['y'];
$type3     = $_POST['z'];`

Comment: what are you getting on the network tab? of your dev tool?

Comment: x,y,z variables i had chenges when i saw the code even then it didnt work.

Comment: is the ajax request fired?

Comment: i think its not fired, because nothing is happening

Comment: add a form then captcha the via when form is submitted

Comment: data.message.success == "ok" // what does this step do. because i think here i am stuck

Comment: add a form then captcha the via when form is submitted – --- i didnt understand this plz can you explain :(

Comment: That step checks if the response from the server is it "ok"

Comment: please help, i think the problem is when you enter username, password and type from form its not getting passed on php page though i have changed $username3 = $_POST['x']; $password3 = $_POST['y']; $type3 = $_POST['z']; to $username3 = $_POST['username2']; $password3 = $_POST['password2']; $type3 = $_POST['type2'];

Comment: masivuye please reply, my query is not executing in php